# Switching imgs in div with an animation / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that switches images in a div for my portfolio site. My question is if there is a possibility of adding an animation when the images switch - FadeOut / FadeIn. I am really new to jQuery, basically just started coding so any help is appreciated!

HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <!--Header-->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logoimg">
        <a href="land.html"><img src="logo.png" width="80px" width="auto"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">Work</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!--Main1-->
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="back1.png" height="400px"; width="700px"></div>
  <ul class="headlines">
    <a href="http://leanart.one/" class="link" data-image-src="back1.png" id="link1">First Website</a>
    <a href="http://leanart.one/GatesNFences/index.html" class="link" data-image-src="back2.png" id="link2">Gates N' Fences</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-image-src="back3.png" id="link3">Storyboard</a>
    <a href="#" class="http://leanart.one/Animation/index.html" data-image-src="back4.png" id="link4">Animation</a>
    <a href="http://leanart.one/animation_interactive%202/animation.html" class="link" data-image-src="back5.png" id="link5">Interactive Animation</a>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-image-src="back6.png" id="link6">Star Wars Game</a>
    <a href="design_manual.pdf" class="link" data-image-src="back7.png" id="link7">Design Manual</a>
    <a href="abeonareport.pdf" class="link" data-image-src="back8.png" id="link8">Abeona</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKEF14_bpQ8" class="link" data-image-src="back9.png" id="link9">Redningsscenarie</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7njS-wF-8wo&feature=youtu.be" class="link" data-image-src="back10.png" id="link10">Don't Mess With Karma</a>
  </ul>
  <!--Footer-->
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="fotext">Copyright Vítek Linhart 2017.</p>
  </footer>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('a').on('mouseover', function() {
        var iSrc = $(this).attr('data-image-src');
        $('.thumbnail img').attr('src', iSrc);
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>
```

This is just the switching function whenever a link hovers it will change the image in a div. And that's when I would like to use an animation so it would look neater.

Comment: Make snippet to make more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a working fiddle with `animate()`. There are lots of other possibilities like `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()` etc. but animate is more versatile as you can animate whatever properties as you like.

Also I cached the `img` element in a `variable` to **improve performance** and prevent JavaScript from traversing the DOM over and over again to find the element. And please don't mind the different sizes of the placeholder images, this is just to show that they actually change:

**EDIT:** You can modify the `duration` variable to change the animation duration.

```js
var duration = 500;
var img_elem = $('.thumbnail img');

$(function() {
 $('a').on('mouseover', function() {
   var iSrc = $(this).data('image-src');
  img_elem.animate({
   opacity:0
  },duration, function(){
   img_elem.attr('src', iSrc).animate({ opacity:1 },duration);
   });      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/700x400" height="400px"; width="700px"></div>
  <ul class="headlines">
    <a href="http://leanart.one/" class="link" data-image-src="http://placehold.it/700x399" id="link1">First Website</a>
    <a href="http://leanart.one/GatesNFences/index.html" class="link" data-image-src="http://placehold.it/700x398" id="link2">Gates N' Fences</a>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery Cycle2 plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). Now, this is a (lightweight) slideshow, but bear with me.

Start Cycle, but do a instant-pause. For your visitors it's like there is only one image, but Cycle has loaded all other slides in the background, is responsive.

```
$('.itemsWrapper').cycle({
    paused: true
    // and others settings to your likings:
    // http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#options
});
```

You can use a 'goto' like functionality. Cycle will fade/slide for you, *saving you a lot of time* trying to create this yourself.

```
$('.gotoSlide').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Clicked on 3rd button? Go to 3rd slide (etc):
    $('.itemsWrapper').cycle( 'goto', $(this).index() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fade the image out, change the src, then fade it back in.

```
$('.thumbnail img').fadeOut('fast', function () {
$('.thumbnail img').attr('src', iSrc);
$('.thumbnail img').fadeIn('fast');
});
```